# phase differences between conical intersections and light-induced conical intersections?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, molecules, theoretical-chemistry

I've read recently about light-induced conical intersections, a phenomenon  where conical intersections can be artificially introduced to molecules, and that this can be observed even in diatomic molecules (see for example [here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0953-4075/44/4/045603/meta) and [here](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.143004) ). I understand that there are similarities in the way you sketch the crossing of the curves, but I dont understand where and how does the wavefunction changes sign near the light-induced conical intersection version?